# Find string in one data frame and replace it in second data frame

Tags: r

In general I have two data frames:

Main one:

```
structure(list(mpg = c(21, 21, 22.8, 21.4, 18.7, 18.1, 14.3, 
24.4, 22.8, 19.2, 17.8, 16.4, 17.3, 15.2, 10.4, 10.4, 14.7, 32.4, 
30.4, 33.9, 21.5, 15.5, 15.2, 13.3, 19.2, 27.3, 26, 30.4, 15.8, 
19.7, 15, 21.4), cyl = c(6, 6, 4, 6, 8, 6, 8, 4, 4, 6, 6, 8, 
8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 8, 8, 8, 4, 4, 4, 8, 6, 8, 4), 
    disp = c(160, 160, 108, 258, 360, 225, 360, 146.7, 140.8, 
    167.6, 167.6, 275.8, 275.8, 275.8, 472, 460, 440, 78.7, 75.7, 
    71.1, 120.1, 318, 304, 350, 400, 79, 120.3, 95.1, 351, 145, 
    301, 121), hp = c(110, 110, 93, 110, 175, 105, 245, 62, 95, 
    123, 123, 180, 180, 180, 205, 215, 230, 66, 52, 65, 97, 150, 
    150, 245, 175, 66, 91, 113, 264, 175, 335, 109), drat = c(3.9, 
    3.9, 3.85, 3.08, 3.15, 2.76, 3.21, 3.69, 3.92, 3.92, 3.92, 
    3.07, 3.07, 3.07, 2.93, 3, 3.23, 4.08, 4.93, 4.22, 3.7, 2.76, 
    3.15, 3.73, 3.08, 4.08, 4.43, 3.77, 4.22, 3.62, 3.54, 4.11
    ), wt = c(2.62, 2.875, 2.32, 3.215, 3.44, 3.46, 3.57, 3.19, 
    3.15, 3.44, 3.44, 4.07, 3.73, 3.78, 5.25, 5.424, 5.345, 2.2, 
    1.615, 1.835, 2.465, 3.52, 3.435, 3.84, 3.845, 1.935, 2.14, 
    1.513, 3.17, 2.77, 3.57, 2.78), qsec = c(16.46, 17.02, 18.61, 
    19.44, 17.02, 20.22, 15.84, 20, 22.9, 18.3, 18.9, 17.4, 17.6, 
    18, 17.98, 17.82, 17.42, 19.47, 18.52, 19.9, 20.01, 16.87, 
    17.3, 15.41, 17.05, 18.9, 16.7, 16.9, 14.5, 15.5, 14.6, 18.6
    ), vs = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1), am = c(1, 
    1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), gear = c("a", "b", "c", 
    "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", 
    "p", "r", "s", "t", "u", "w", "z", "a1", "b1", "c1", "d1", 
    "e1", "f1", "g1", "h1", "i1"), carb = c("Mazda RX4", "Mazda RX4 Wag", 
    "Datsun 710", "Hornet 4 Drive", "Hornet Sportabout", "Valiant", 
    "Duster 360", "Merc 240D", "Merc 230", "Merc 280", "Merc 280C", 
    "Merc 450SE", "Merc 450SL", "Merc 450SLC", "Cadillac Fleetwood", 
    "Lincoln Continental", "Chrysler Imperial", "Fiat 128", "Honda Civic", 
    "Toyota Corolla", "Toyota Corona", "Dodge Challenger", "AMC Javelin", 
    "Camaro Z28", "Pontiac Firebird", "Fiat X1-9", "Porsche 914-2", 
    "Lotus Europa", "Ford Pantera L", "Ferrari Dino", "Maserati Bora", 
    "Volvo 142E")), .Names = c("mpg", "cyl", "disp", "hp", "drat", 
"wt", "qsec", "vs", "am", "gear", "carb"), row.names = c(NA, 
-32L), class = "data.frame")
```

Table with names:

```
    structure(list(car = structure(c(18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 5L, 13L, 
14L, 31L, 7L, 21L, 20L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 2L, 15L, 4L, 
9L, 12L, 29L, 30L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 27L, 10L, 28L, 16L, 11L, 11L, 
8L, 17L, 32L, 32L), .Label = c("AMC Javelin", "Cadillac Fleetwood", 
"Camaro Z28", "Chrysler Imperial", "Datsun 710", "Dodge Challenger", 
"Duster 360", "Ferrari Dino", "Fiat 128", "Fiat X1-9", "Ford Pantera L", 
"Honda Civic", "Hornet 4 Drive", "Hornet Sportabout", "Lincoln Continental", 
"Lotus Europa", "Maserati Bora", "Mazda RX4", "Mazda RX4 Wag", 
"Merc 230", "Merc 240D", "Merc 280", "Merc 280C", "Merc 450SE", 
"Merc 450SL", "Merc 450SLC", "Pontiac Firebird", "Porsche 914-2", 
"Toyota Corolla", "Toyota Corona", "Valiant", "Volvo 142E"), class = "factor"), 
    owner = structure(c(15L, 25L, 9L, 8L, 4L, 7L, 31L, 22L, 17L, 
    6L, 12L, 32L, 12L, 19L, 1L, 3L, 11L, 20L, 26L, 27L, 24L, 
    29L, 16L, 1L, 2L, 13L, 9L, 26L, 23L, 10L, 18L, 14L, 30L, 
    28L, 5L, 21L), .Label = c("Amid", "Armin", "Crane", "Dietmar", 
    "Gared", "Gratea", "Hank", "Hannea", "Hans", "Heta", "Horse_with_no_name", 
    "Jeff", "Krea", "Marea", "Mark", "Mattheus", "Micha", "Miko", 
    "Myrcella", "Neil", "Nina", "Peter", "Rene", "Robert", "Steffan", 
    "Tim", "Timon", "Timothy", "Uwe", "Vincent", "Wolfram", "Yena"
    ), class = "factor")), .Names = c("car", "owner"), row.names = c(NA, 
-36L), class = "data.frame")
```

So I would like to add additional column to my main data frame with the name of the `owner`. The `owners` of each of the car you can find in the second data.

BUT:

As you already noticed some of the cars might have different owners. I don't want to create additional rows in my main data frame so I would like to put two/three or more owners in the same row but separated by coma for example.

Comment: Have you tried `merge`, `match` etc?

Comment: there is a defect in your data: in column 10 of the main dataframe, one value is missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
library(data.table)
res <- setDT(df1, key='car')[df2][,c(.SD[1L],
           list(ownerN=toString(owner))), car][,owner:=NULL]
head(res,2)
#             car mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#1:     Mazda RX4  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#2: Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#          ownerN
#1: Mark, Steffan
#2:  Hans, Hannea
```

Or alternatively `paste` the 'owner' by 'car' in 'df2' and join with the 'df1'

```
 dt2 <- setDT(df2)[, .(owner=toString(owner)), by= car]
 setkey(setDT(df1), car)[dt2]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- cbind(mtcars, car=row.names(mtcars))
row.names(df1) <- NULL
df2[] <- lapply(df2, as.character)
```

Comment: I get this error and I have no idea why because it looks like it's working perfect for you: `Error in setDT(df1, key = "car") : unused argument (key = "car")`

Comment: @ShaxiLiver The `df1` you created was defective (as from the ColonelBeauvel's comments). Assuming that you are using the same dataset as I created, the `key='car'` is a new feature in the devel version.  You can try `setkey(setDT(df1), car)` if you don't have the devel version.

Answer (score 3):

I'd make your second dataframe a data table (which I call dt2) and then you can do:

```
dt2 <- dt2[ , list( 'owner' = toString(owner)) , by = car ]
```

And then just join that onto your first data table.

Edit: I do like the addition of "toString" by @akrun

Comment: This error is printed out after starting the code: `Error in `[.data.frame`(dt2, , list(owner = list(owner)), by = car) : 
  unused argument (by = car)`

Comment: I think you need to make it a data table. So load in the data.table library, and then create the data by wrapping it with data.table(), like:

    dt2 <- data.table(your_data_structure)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you would do that but if you want to regroup owners in the same row and separate them by a comma :

```
library(dplyr)
df2 %>% 
  group_by(car) %>% 
  summarise(owner = paste(owner, collapse = ", ")) %>% 
  inner_join(df1, by = c("car" = "carb"))

# Which gives for example :
        car         owner mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear
1 Mazda RX4 Mark, Steffan  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.62 16.46  0  1    4
```

Comment: It looks like I have a serious problem with RStudio: `Error: cannot join on columns 'car' x 'carb': Can't join on 'car' x 'carb' because of incompatible types (character / numeric) `. Similar problem as above...

Comment: The "main" dataframe you created is defective, you have to join on the right columns. Replace car and carb by the columns you want to make the join, if they have the same name use only one string for exemple : `by = "car"`